# Create Next App typescript not working when Dev Server is run

Tags: typescript, next.js, create-react-app

I tried setting up a nextjs+typescript app using `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` command, everything was installed fine but when I run the dev function I got this error about Global CSS

```bash
error - ../../../#Typescript/NextJsTS/ts-next/styles/globals.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-globalLocation: ..\..\..\#Typescript\NextJsTS\ts-next\pages\_app.tsx
```

My folder structure is like this-

```
•pages
      •api
      •_app.tsx
      •index.tsx
•styles
      •globals.css
      •Home.module.css
```

My _app.tsx file is -

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

I tried commenting out the global.css import but then I got this other error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have imported the global.css file to other files. try removing any importation from any other file than the _app.tsx file. But if it is the first time after creating the next app it should have work properly

Comment: It was some issue with .pnpm-store folder, I deleted the folder and it is working fine now